# WKWebView - Xamarin code to extract, store and display web page along the resources (img, font, js, css etc.) for offline viewing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

Is there any library in Xamarin which would store the pages that we browse in WKWebView?

Have to store the resources of the pages (CSS, fonts, js etc.) for offline viewing. The complexity is maintaining the folder structure and manage the resource Urls within the CSS and JS files. Any idea how the resources can be stored and loaded?

There are resources on how to save a html page and load the html in WKWebView.
Please note that this question is not about that. It is more about storing and managing the resources of the visited pages for offline viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to get your answer with a mobile only approach.  It's not impossible to create one but I don't believe anything exists that will do what you want, happy to be proven wrong.  I think you need to think outside the square a bit.

I can't give you the entire set of code because I don't own it (my company does) but I managed to take a website completely offline (with limitations of course) by using multiple resources to achieve the desired outcome.

I used a piece of software called Cyotek WebCopy in an Azure VM to scrape all of the website down to a folder.  That folder was then zipped up and uploaded to Azure Blob Storage so it could be accessed from anywhere.  The Xamarin app would then access the storage container, retrieve all of the blobs and then when a user clicks on a specific blob, it unzips down to the device and then opens up in a web view for the user to browse.

All of this was achieved using a web service and PowerShell scripts on the VM side and then of course your standard Xamarin based application for viewing.

Like I said, there are limitations to this but barring external links and database calls (like a submission page), it will work for you.  It has worked for us.

It may sound like a lot of work but all in all, the VM side took me about 2 days and the Xamarin concept about 5 so all in all, not long to stand something up that is able to be built upon.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detail info. The dynamic site would be out of sync if zipped in advance. But the problem is offline storage is for offline viewing. i.e. no internet connection. So downloading is not going to work?

Comment: Well, I figure you have to be online at some stage to access the site anyway so regardless, that is a requirement. I’m not sure what you mean by offline storage is for offline viewing but when I download the zip file from storage, it’s on the device and therefore, you can take the device offline and still access the site. The zip file stays there until you delete it. As for site being out of sync, yep it’s a constraint and all depends on how dynamic the site is but everything you sound like you’re wanting relates to an offline site which has obvious challenges.

Comment: User would be online and browsing the site (within WKWebView). At that point we have to store the pages that the user browses. Once stored we can load the stored page (only the ones user visited) in offline mode. However storing the resources with the hierarchy and folder structure would require lots of parsing of the html as well as css and js files.

Comment: Ok, you’re scenario is slightly different. You could do it on a smaller scale though. Rather than using my entire framework, when you access the page, call the service to scrape it and once finished, grab a callback, save locally and use later. The only constraint is if the user goes offline before the scrape of the page is done, we’re talking edge cases though.

Comment: That sounds good. User going offline before storage is not going to e an issu as we can track which pages are available for offline and handle it in the WKWebView delegates.

I was wondering since the page and the resources are already loaded in the WKWebView (while online), if there is any way to get and store those resources on the mobile end without downloading again or getting the processed content from the server. This would save bandwidth.
I can get the html but not the resources.

Comment: “Getting the processed content from the server” is, I think, basically the solution I’m proposing and as for interrogating and making use of a browsers cache, that’s a challenging one. I’ve never seen something that does it with any conviction, hence why things like scrapers exist, they do it at run time. I reckon it’s worth a POC. If you’re interested I can probably send you some code. Keen? I’m interested to know how it would go.

Comment: Sorry, I reread your reply, ignore my initial paragraph in my last comment, start from “interrogating” 

Comment: I was not planning to deal with the browser cache on the mobile side as WKWebView already removed the offline cache option which was working with UIWebView.
Do you have codes for the scrapper? Then I can use that on the mobile end to scrap and download the resources. I am wondering how the scrapper would process the Urls within the js and CSS files. That is one of the objective of this question.

Comment: It’s very robust. If you want to check it out, it’s a free piece of software ... https://www.cyotek.com/cyotek-webcopy ... JS is more challenging though. Be sure to read it’s limitations. Bottom line, just try it and see how it behaves.